# Where to place an artificial oceanic island?

Tags: geography, ocean, megastructures

I want to build a seastead in international waters that starts small. It has to be in the Atlantic, preferably in the northern hemisphere close to either the american or european continent.

Due to the initial small size of the seastead what would be a place with calm waters and relatively free of storms that is found in the described area?

Comment: `what would be a place with calm waters and relatively free of storms` At the bottom of the ocean?

Comment: @Adrian Colomitchi are there islands at the bottom of the oceans?

Comment: if there aren't yet, there may be. Wannabe seasteads, mainly, yes. :grin: Seriously speaking, corrosion, fatigue, bio-fouling, extreme weather - those are just a few problem in designing floating structures at sea. 't's gonna be expensive as hell to have one lasting more than 10 years, the first to take this route will be the wealthy in the search for (tax?) shelters. And they'll do it only after anything else will prove too expensive - which means it will be a long time to see anyone trying.

Comment: Are you looking for a floating platform of an actual island, the latter will have to be built on an existing seamount.

Comment: yeah I mean a floating structure

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Near the African coasts, a little south of the Straits of Gibraltar.

Look for minimum precipitation, minimum wind speed and wave height charts. Also, perturbation paths for the Atlantic Hurricane Season.

These charts do not coincide completely - for example the average wave height would be lower off the Canarias:

[image]

but on average, on the whole year, the Atlantic is a challenging environment:

[image]

If all possible, moving on a 8-shape to "follow" the seasonally calmer areas could be a solution.

However, I think that a floating *island* should be robust enough to withstand all but the most powerful hurricanes.

Comment: if the island is not tethered in one place it will eventually end up in the Sargasso Sea.

Comment: I like the figure 8 course for mobile island.   You could also have sails on it, and maybe a mermaid on the prow.